# Disable the "s" restriction temporarily in the closed beta?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-declined, tags

In general, most sites that are similar to ours prefer the plural or collective forms of nouns for tags rather than singular... e.g., on cooking, the tags are "doughnuts", "vegetables", "measurements", etc. Exceptions are made when necessary, generally when meaning is changed or when the singular is also a collective term, e.g. "chicken", "beef", "steak", etc.

I strongly encourage this practice, personally... if we want to have a discussion about it, we can create a topic but I think there's sufficient precedence to not need one... regardless...

Unfortunately, there's also a lovely (not sarcastic) system in place that prevents users from creating plural versions of existing tags... even if the goal is to delete the singular version of the tag simultaneously.

If a tag is created in its singular form in error (like the [pencil](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pencil) is currently), will we need to come here to request the CMs intervention in every case (until we get mods) or is it possible to temporarily remove the plural tag restriction so that we can do it ourselves?

Comment: Yes! I hate singular forms for tags! All tags should be plural form where appropriate in my opinion

Comment: So why did you create one? ;)

Comment: For [pencil]? It wouldn't let me. I tried creating pencils, but then it stopped me. In fact, I was going to come to meta and complain when I found the nerve to :)

Comment: Oh, gotcha! I didn't realize that it existed before you asked your question. I didn't look at the question count... wait... it didn't exist... now I'm confused. Where's Robert when you need him.

Comment: Allowing plural + single tags is not a great solution. It only exasperates the problem when users start using *both* tags. There's no guarantee that the plural tag is only "temporary". The best way to handle this is to rename the *existing* flag; not to create another one.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I don't think we're proposing having *two* tags, but we want the names of the tags to be in plural form. Sadly, we can't change this because the one tag exists

Comment: @RobertCartaino So can you at least fix the pencil tag and explain why Ziz wasn't able to create the plural in the first place?

Comment: @Zizouz212 I had just fixed it before posting this.

Comment: So, this is technically half "completed" and half "declined" :P Is asking here the best solution for if this happens again?

Comment: You can flag a post if the problem is obvious ("Can you rename this tag to `pencils`?") or you can ask a question in meta if the issue might need more discussion.

Comment: Use `pencilz`, it even makes you look cooler.